# How can anomalies in QKD be detected?

Tags: quantum-information

In Quantum Key Distribution, a secret key is shared between Alice and Bob using entangled photons (generally). If an eavesdropper (Eve) measures the photons during transmission they introduce anomalies in the data recorded by the receiver and these are detected to alert the users of Eve.

But how do Alice and Bob detect there is an anomaly? They cannot compare results as this would compromise their keys.

Answer (score 4):

Alice and Bob will choose a subset of the rounds which they will use to test the protocol. These test-rounds will not be used to produce the final key. In the test-rounds they can for example play the CHSH-game to test their entanglement and by monogamy of entanglement conclude that Eve is ignorant of their correlations. It's important that Eve does not know which rounds Alice and Bob will test until after the first phase. If she does not know which rounds will be tested it is very unlikely that she will manage to intercept only the rounds used to produce key.